# Connect to Oracle in a website .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, web

I want to connect my website to Oracle. I have the connection string in web.config file. The sample is:

```
<add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=DB;USER ID=USER;Password=xxxxx" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

In my .cs file, when I try to do:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client
```

, it throws namespace not found error.

Please let me know what should I do use Oracle libraries.
I am able to connect to Oracle in a console/web form application after I add a reference, but unable to do in a website application.

Comment: You should be able to add the reference in the same way as with the web form application

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a DLL to reference, add a reference to it in the project (you may have to select 'Show All' to get References to show up in the project tree), and then it should be good in the import. (You forgot a semicolon at the end of the line too :) )

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked when I right-clicked Solution and added a reference. I am using VS2010, I am unable to view Show All files.If possible, please let me know where to find it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But, I am unable to see this in the solution explorer. I am using VS2010.

Comment: My Bad. I was using a Website instead of a Web application. On using a Web application, I could see the Show all files.